# sql - for every unique value in column sample 2 different values from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, statistics

I am stuck on a  sql aggregate problem.

Consider the following table/view:

```
Column1  Column2
1        2564
2        6550
1        3578
2        6548
2        4789
1        9876
```

I would like to design a query to do the following:

For every distinct Column1 value, sample 2x records. The sampling strategy could be some some sort of bootstrapping/resampling as there might not too many data points.

Thus the table will become:

```
Column1     Column2
1           9876
1           3578
2           6548
2           6550
```

Platform: MS SQL

Any answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a random sample without replacement:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column1 order by newid()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Or, alternatively:

```
select top (2) with ties t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by newid());
```

For a random sample with replacement:

With replacement:

```
select *
from ((select top (1) with ties t.*
       from t
       order by row_number() over (partition by id order by newid())
      )
      union all
      (select top (1) with ties t.*
       from t
       order by row_number() over (partition by id order by newid())
      )
     ) x;
```

Comment: I wanted to pick 15 unique rows and have simply extended the code with the replacement option. It worked like a charm. Thank you!